# SQL - Compare rows in different tables

Tags: sql, compare

**Table1**

```
Mem HCC2017     
--- -------
A   HCC19                   
A   HCC12               
B   HCC67                   
B   HCC132              
B   HCC190              
C   HCC88

D   HCC91

E   HCC20
```

**Table2**

```
Member  HCC2018     
--- ---------
A   HCC14                   
A   HCC101              
A   HCC20               
A   HCC55               
B   HCC33

B   HCC131
```

I want to only exclude the row from Table1:

1. where there is same HCC in both the year (eg. MemberA has same HCC101 in botht the tables)
2. where there is HCC19 in Table1.HCC2017 and (HCC20 or HCC21) in Table2.HCC2018, (eg. Member A)
3. where there is HCC132 in Table1.HCC2017 and HCC131 in Table2.HCC2018  (eg.Member B)

**Resulting Dataset**

```
A   HCC12               
A   HCC18   
B   HCC67                       
B   HCC190              
C   HCC88

D   HCC91

E   HCC20
```

I tried using case statements in different ways but I am not getting the desired results. I keep going deeper and deeper into the rabbit hole!

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
INTO #TEST
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
H7.MEMBER
,H7.HCC2017
,H8.HCC2018
,CASE  
WHEN H7.HCC2017 ='HCC19' AND H8.HCC2018 in ('HCC20','HCC21') THEN 1 
WHEN H7.HCC2017 ='HCC132' AND H8.HCC2018 ='HCC131' THEN 1 
WHEN H7.HCC2017 = H8.HCC2018 THEN 1

ELSE 0
END AS MATCH


FROM Table1 H7
LEFT JOIN Table2 H8 ON H7.MEMBER = H8.MEMBER
)A

WHERE MATCH = 0

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #TEST
```

Comment: Can you share with us in how different ways ..?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: you had better editing your question with this info, instead of commenting.

Comment: @DavideCasiraghi I basically want to compare 1 row from Table1 to multiple rows in Table2

Comment: Can you post your query code ? So we can have a starting point to work from?

Comment: @DavideCasiraghi : I edited my question with the query